# Laravel elixir - more specific error messages from gulp

Tags: less, gulp, laravel-elixir

I'm receiving the following error when trying to compile the less files for a theme that I purchased that was packaged with less files.  Here's the output I'm seeing:

```
$ gulp
[22:53:49] Using gulpfile ~/path/to/gulpfile.js
[22:53:49] Starting 'default'...
[22:53:49] Starting 'less'...
[22:53:49] Running Less: resources/assets/less/style.less
[22:53:49] Finished 'default' after 524 ms
[22:53:50] gulp-notify: [Laravel Elixir] Less Compilation Failed!: no writecb in Transform class
[Error: no writecb in Transform class]
```

How can I obtain a more specific error message?  Googling this error message yielded no useful results.

Comment: From : http://irclogs.laravel.io/2015-04-20/21:52#log-5535750377c0282818000bdd : so yeah, if anyone comes in with the same question as i do, the current version of laravel-elixir is broken since gulp-less@3.0.3 seems to be broken. you'd first have to install gulp-less@3.0.2 and then laravel-elixir

Comment: @BassJobsen Why not post that as a solution so I can give you credit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From : http://irclogs.laravel.io/2015-04-20/21:52#log-5535750377c0282818000bdd

> so yeah, if anyone comes in with the same question as i do, the current >version of laravel-elixir is broken since gulp-less@3.0.3 seems to be broken. >you'd first have to install gulp-less@3.0.2 and then laravel-elixir

So when this solution helps you, credits should go to @madwasp at irclogs.laravel.io.

I also think: https://github.com/plus3network/gulp-less/issues/166 confirms the issue with gulp-less@3.0.3